# How do I properly modify a .def file in a Visual C++ 6 program?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, linker

I'm doing maintenance on a C++ 6.0 project that uses a .def file to handle function exports. I had to add a pair of instance methods to a class definition, but I don't know how to add these methods to the .def file so they get exported. Each line under the EXPORTS section in the .def file looks something like `?MethodName@ClassName@@AStringOfLetters` with maybe a `@Z` tacked on the end for no reason I can fathom. I'm assuming the string of letters corresponds in some way to the prototype of the method, but I can't find any documentation that describes the encoding. The methods I added don't have a prototype that exactly matches any of the existing methods.

Let's say my new method prototypes look like this:

```
  short ClassName::Foo1(const short, const unsigned int, const short, const unsigned int *);
  short ClassName::Foo2(const short, const unsigned int, short *, unsigned int *);
```

What do I need to add to the .def file in order to make my linker happy and actually export the methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are exporting the C++ mangled symbols.  I would add a `__declspec(dllexport)` in front of them temporarily and then load the DLL in something like Dependency Walker, or use `dumpbin` to see what is exported.  This will give you the mangled symbol for you new functions and then you can add that to the .def file and remove the `__declspec`.

Answer (score 0):

To get the mangled name for your new functions, just comment out the implementation and build the project. This way you would get a liker error showing the mangled name of your new function. Update your def file with this new mangled name.